# ElasticSearch geo-database: geo_distance filter returns geo pins in ellipse not in circle

Tags: google-maps, elasticsearch

i have elasticsearch database of geo objects.
I want to search the nearest objects around some `geo_point` in custom distance and then display them on google map.
using default elasticsearch filters - `geo_distance` filter, it works fine, but the problem is that returned pins are in eliptical range, not in circular range (as usually when you search anything in X km RADIUS) maybe screenshots would help to understand.

I don't know where the problem can be, google maps only takes the result that elastic returns - set of pins to display

Does anybody know anything about this issue?

[image: map without filtering]

[image: filtered map, the red circle shows actual border of searching]

Comment: Could you recreate the issue by selecting one point on the north side of your circle that is included in the result and one point on the west/east side of your circle that should be included but is not? Index both points and provide the query that you are using to generate this map.

Comment: Ok. Center pin: `[48.8534100, 2.3488000]`  Distance filter is `3km`.    Pin near the north circle border: `[48.8801108681, 2.35152032666]`,    then pin that should be on map on west circle border,   but it is not has point  `[48.85265,2.308896]`   .... and pin near the west border of ellipse is `[48.8543679, 2.3239985]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When geo points are represented as arrays in elasticsearch they are following GeoJSON format, which is `[lon, lat]`. So, from elasticsearch perspective, your center pin is not in Paris but just off the coast of Somalia.

Comment: YES!!! This is it! In example on elasticsearch.org is [lat,lon] and I didn't notice the right syntax of that GeoJSON array [lon,lat]. The object coordinates was ok, but I rotated the Earth by 90° :-)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your screenshots I came up with a couple of points in your circle.

Assuming we have centre coordinate of lat:48.853647, lon:2.347894, and a point at lat:48.853647 lon:2.32 (a point at the same lat but further west):

Using distance_type:plane the distance calculated is ~ 3.1km, while using distance_type:arc the distance is ~ 2km.

If we use a different point, lat:48.8717 lon:2.347894 (further north of the centre point, but some lon), using distance_type:plane the distance is ~ 2km and using distance_type:arc it is also ~ 2km.

Consequently if the filtered distance was say 2.5km, then using distance_type:arc would correctly include both points, while using distance_type:plane would only include the northern point, giving the elliptical shape.

Comment: I agree that this is the most likely reason. However, according to http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/why-geo-distance-is-filtering-in-elliptical-shape-td3914855.html Ondrej tried using both arc distance_type and plane distance_type without success.

Comment: That's true, actually these screenshots are taken using ARC type.

Comment: I have used the coordinates you gave in your earlier comment and the math I present here still checks out.  With distance_type:arc the point at the western border of the circle is ~2.9km, with distance_type:plane it is ~4km.  Comparatively with the point on the western edge on the ellipse, the arc distance is ~1.8km while the plane distance is ~2.7km.  Somehow somewhere the PLANE type must be being used.